# How to get a variable value outside a callback function NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm trying to get the value of an inputed variable on a callback function and assign it into another variable value outside this callback function.
I'm using async/await but not working (the assignment runs before the callback function), any suggestion?

```
async function iniciar() {
    let my_prep = '';
    await readline.question('Insert preposition', (prep) => {
      **my_prep = prep;**
      readline.close();
    });
    console.log('OK',my_prep);
    return true;
}
```

[image]

Thanks for reading!

Comment: await keyword waits on promise does your function `readline.question` returns a promise?

Comment: Readline's question() function does not return Promise or result of the arrow function. So, cannot use then() with it. @alt255

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
const question = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readline.question('Insert preposition ', (prep) => {
      readline.close();
      resolve(prep)
    })
  })
}



async function iniciar() {
  let my_prep = await question();
  console.log('OK',my_prep);
  return true;
}
```

await keyword waits on the promise to resolve, so you need to return promise. Also the use of `async/await` and `promises` is to avoid callback hell.

Comment: Exactly want I needed! Thanks for the reply! @alt255